# django admin detail page showing blank without error

Tags: python, django, model, row, dashboard

It is really weird that when I go into my django admin dashboard, choose one of the model under an app then go into one of the row's detail.  The detail is just a blank.

For example, I have an app named Product then a model named Sku under the product app. And of course there are quite data in the sku but when I click into one of the sku's data, the page is blank.

Steps for example,

- I login into my django admin dashboard
- I see the sku model listed under product app
- clicked the sku then see a list of sku info
- I choose one of the sku info to click into
- I should then see the detail of this sku I clicked but instead I see blank page without errors
- This does not apply to all models just 1-2 models
- anyone have any idea reason and where I should look into?

[image]

P.S. I tried to use `python manage.py collectstatic` also, my development
is totally fine though.

Anyone has idea what might be the reason?
Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

models.py

```
class Media(TimeStampedDeletionModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank=True, null=True)

    behance = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    dribbble = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    flickr = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.profile)
```

admin.py

```
class MediaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('profile', 'facebook')
    list_display_links = ('profile', 'facebook')
    search_fields = ('profile__email', 'facebook')

admin.site.register(Media, MediaAdmin)
```

Comment: Same happening to me, any luck finding the cause?

Comment: @OzgurAkcali for me I figured, it was some `unicode` issue for example for my `self.profile`, I actually did something to it which causes pretty much everything that has to do with it will show blank without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today on my local machine running development server (i.e. ./manage.py runserver): all of a sudden add/change admin page of one of my apps was simply displaying blank page, like  block was completely deleted. I had no code changes and it was a simple page, nothing on the empty page was relying on javascript code or anything like that, was logged in with super user and had all permissions even though no apps locally rely on any model permissions. So what I did - I just set DEBUG to False and restarted the dev server, did a couple of  in Chrome browser and then set the DEBUG back to True and the issue was fixed, hope this helps somebody as I wasted almost 2 hours on this..